# Could Thanos have created more resources rather than kill half of the population? MCU

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos, the-infinity-gauntlet

How powerful are the Infinity Stones when they are all combined in the Infinity Gauntlet? Thanos states that he wants to kill half of the population in order to ensure that there are enough resources to go around. Could he have made more resources instead of killing half of the population or is the combined power of the stones limited in what they can create?

I thought maybe he could have changed the structure of uninhabitable worlds into viable worlds for beings to live on but then that would only be a short term solution depending on how many planets can be made viable. Or possibly even broken down some of those uninhabitable planets/stars/asteroids into their elements and distributed "more resources" to the planets with living beings.

Comment: The problem isnt that there's too many people, it's that they'll run out of resources in a finite timescale. If you double the resources, you push that timescale back a bit but it doesn't fix the problem. And it might make it worse because now people can breed out of control..in a few generations you're back to square one. People need to be ***taught a lesson***.

Comment: What sort of villain would he be if he made everyone's life better, instead of killing half of them and then blaming the folks who don't thank him for it?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is Thanos's motivation for his action?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186626/what-is-thanoss-motivation-for-his-action)

Comment: Also a dupe of [If lack of resources was the true motivation for MCU Thanos' mission, why didn't he just use the Infinity Gauntlet to make more?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228938/if-lack-of-resources-was-the-true-motivation-for-mcu-thanos-mission-why-didnt)

Comment: @Valorum but if you kill half of the people you just push back the timescale again. People will still have the same tech to with just not as many people. They will start breeding again and spread just as fast as before .

Comment: @ZeissIkon that is why I am questioning his motivation did he really need to be a villain? The answer is obviously yes because he is Thanos but this motivation doesn't seem like he needed to be a villain.

Comment: He should have been able to make a limitless supply of resources if he really wanted to.  That was the weakness of changing his motivations from the comic version, where death was the whole point of it.

Comment: @rzartx - The people who got snapped will recognise that they need to live in harmony with their surroundings or face the same fate a second time. It's not just about removing numbers but also dealing out an object lesson.

Comment: @valorum The people who got snapped are dead, and Thanos went so far as to destroy the stones to prevent that being undone.  The lesson is only for those who survived -- and those of them who think like humans wouldn't tend to accept it as such.

Comment: But know one knew why their friends and family died. To my knowledge Thanos never broadcast to everyone why he did what he did. Hard to teach a lesson when everyone has know idea what is happening.

Comment: @rzaratx - I'm sure people can take a hint. Plus with only half the population they'd experience a new golden age that they wouldn't want to end by re-populating.